# How to specify the allocator with boost::allocate_shared?

Tags: c++, performance, memory

I'm trying to improve performance of boost::shared_ptr by using allocate_shared. The thing is I'm unsure what kind of allocator I should exactly pass to boost::allocate_shared.

I have the below:

```cpp
struct MagicalData {...};

// My simple allocator example 
template <typename T>
class MyAlloc
{
 public:

typedef T                 value_type;
typedef value_type*       pointer;
typedef const value_type* const_pointer;
typedef value_type&       reference;
typedef const value_type& const_reference;
typedef std::size_t       size_type;
typedef std::ptrdiff_t    difference_type;

template<typename U>
struct rebind {
    typedef MyAlloc<U> other;
};  

pointer allocate(size_type n, const_pointer = 0) {
    void* p = std::malloc(n * sizeof(T));
    if (!p)
      throw std::bad_alloc();
    return static_cast<pointer>(p);
}   

void deallocate(pointer p, size_type) {
    std::free(p);
}   

size_type max_size() const { 
    return static_cast<size_type>(-1) / sizeof(value_type);
}   
};
```

MyAlloc alloc;

```
// Compilation error
boost::shared_ptr<MagicalData> magicalData 
       = boost::allocate_shared<MagicalData>(alloc, j);
```

I get the puzzling compilation error here:

`/usr/include/boost-1_51/boost/smart_ptr/detail/shared_count.hpp:239:18: error: no matching function for call to ‘MyAlloc<boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_pda<MagicalData*, boost::detail::sp_ms_deleter<MagicalData>, MyAlloc<MagicalData> > >::MyAlloc(MyAlloc<MagicalData>&)'`

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your `MagicalData` default-constructible?

Comment: Yes default constructible and copy constructible.

Comment: Wait a minute, none of this should compile, because you're missing `typename` in like a thousand places...

Comment: All the definitions are inlined directly into the class so I don't think I need typename.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I missed this. From wiki: Allocators should be copy-constructible. An allocator for objects of type T can be constructed from an allocator for objects of type U. If an allocator, A, allocates a region of memory, R, then R can only be deallocated by an allocator that compares equal to A.[11]